# Very slow Ethereum sync

Tags: synchronization, fast-sync

I was around block 2.5 million on a "full" sync and I think it would've taken months to fully sync. At times the blockchain grew faster than my computer was syncing.

I moved that directory over to a new name and now had an empty directory to restart. I used `geth -syncmode="fast"`. This worked for about 48 hours. My cellphone is my wifi hotspot and it gave out on me. So it finished the "fast" portion and started going over the blocks again. I assume downloading the "real data."

Things were good... until I hit block # ~2.2 million. I'm on a 50mpbs fiber connection at work and getting 1,2 maybe 3 blocks anywhere between 1-3 minutes. After my cellphone gave out I went to the library and was getting 60-110 blocks every 8 seconds (1.7-2.2 million).

I wish I had speed tested all the networks I've been on but none are slow. My phone isn't 100% reliable due to my location but until I hit 150GB this billing cycle it was pretty fast.

Is there anything that can be done to help it along? Is this a "slow spot" in the sync?

I assume after the "fast" portion is done and the program goes back over the chain to download the actual blocks... it no longer is downloading the headers of the new blocks? Would this be true?

Trying to get my tokens off an exchange into a private wallet. Intended on using Mist. Not having much luck. Been a very slow crawl to block 2335167. Anything I can do? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you syncing on a HDD? From geth developers: ["Geth requires an SSD currently."](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/16218#issuecomment-369928057), it is impossible to sync with HDD. They recommend to use the light mode with a HDD [What is Geth's "light" sync, and why is it so fast?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/11297/what-is-geths-light-sync-and-why-is-it-so-fast).

Around the point of 2.4-2.7M blocks are the DoS attacks suffered by the network ([Why did the Fast sync stop at 2.4 million blocks when updating my Geth?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/18334/why-did-the-fast-sync-stop-at-2-4-million-blocks-when-updating-my-geth)).

Comment: Yes HDD. Your information was very useful.