# Why does the mainnet download take a long time? How can I improve this?

Tags: synchronization, fast-sync

We have been working on integrating a ETH node to our e-wallet to enable ether transactions. We completely build the platform by connecting to a private Ethereum network. 
Now everything is ready to go on to the mainnet. I started the download (fast download) last Thursday, any by today it had only downloaded about 108 GB. And the download speed has drastically decreased in the last few days. At this rate I feel like it will take forever to sync the blockchain. After searching for a while I found a article which said to use a VPN to change the location. I tried this out but the download speed didn't improve much.

I'm I doing anything wrong? Are there any other recommendations to improve the download speed?

Comment: Currently the problem is not the download speed but the IO required to build the "Ethereum World Status", here is a longer explanation from a developer https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/16218#issuecomment-371454280.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The slow down is because around the point of 2.4-2.7M blocks are the
>   DoS attacks suffered by the network
>   ([Why did the Fast sync stop at 2.4 million blocks when updating my Geth?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/18334/why-did-the-fast-sync-stop-at-2-4-million-blocks-when-updating-my-geth)).

Based on your requirements, you might be fine using a light client. Running `parity --light db kill` followed by `parity --light` will get you up and running in hours.

Answer (score 0):

Here are few pointers:

- Use parity
- use **--pruning** Fast mode
- use **--cache-size** of at least 1024MB (default is 128kb)
- make sure your server has SSD disk
- make sure at least 4gb of memory is present

Confirm above and start parity node. After 6 hours, just attach to geth and see for yourself that your node has synced.

bonus: if you want to sync entire node (1TB) use --pruning=archive (might take a day or two)

Comment: The 1.2 TB --pruning archive node takes a lot longer than a day or two. It's at least a week on my relatively capable Linux box. The --tracing on (without --pruning=archive) which takes up about 120 GB.