# Make Hyperledger Besu sync faster during DOS blocks

Tags: ethereumj, besu

I am attempting to sync a full node using Hyperledger Besu and it has slowed down considerably when hitting about block 2,300,000.
Geth and Parity can be made faster as this link details to sync these as detailed her:
[Why did the Fast sync stop at 2.4 million blocks when updating my Geth?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/18334/why-did-the-fast-sync-stop-at-2-4-million-blocks-when-updating-my-geth)

What are the best settings for Besu?

Comment: Trying to run in windows with java directly instead of a docker container on WSL2. It seems to be a lot faster.  Maybe RocksDB over docker wsl2 isn't very performant...

Answer (score 1):

found the settings:

--target-gas-limit=1500000 --min-gas-price=20000000000